# Jenkins integration to Protractor project

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jasmine, continuous-integration, protractor

I am try to do Jenkins integration for my protractor project.I am using Protractor, Jasmine to write the test. I configure the project in Visual studio with nodeJs.

I can run all test manually.Now, I am aiming to try the Jenkins integration so my project can run continuously.

Please suggests me the way or any helpful media.
My 'RunConf.js' file is as below. I use this file to run both the suites.

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine2',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
capabilities:
{
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'shardTestFiles': true,
    'maxInstances': 2,
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['chrome.switches', '--disable-extensions']
    }
},
suites: {
    loginpage: 'login.js',
    addproduct: 'addproduct.js'
},
//specs: ['addproduct.js'],
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,
    isVerbose: false,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
},

onPrepare: function () {
    browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
        browser.getCapabilities().then(function(value) {
            reportName = value.get(Math.random(8,2)) + '_' + value.get('browserName') + '_' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1E16);
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
                new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
                    //cleanDestination: false,
                    savePath: 'target/',
                    docTitle: 'Web UI Test Report',
                    screenshotsFolder: 'image',
                    //takeScreenshots: true,
                    takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
                    consolidate: true,
                    consolidateAll: true,
                   // preserveDirectory: true,
                    //fixedScreenshotName: true,
                    filePrefix: reportName + ".html"
                })
            );
            fulfill();
        });
    });
},
afterLaunch: function afterLaunch() {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var output = '';
    fs.readdirSync('target/').forEach(function(file) {
        if (!(fs.lstatSync('target/' + file).isDirectory()))
            output = output + fs.readFileSync('target/' + file);
    });
    fs.writeFileSync('target/ConsolidatedReport.html', output, 'utf8');
}
```

}

Comment: You are more likely to get a response if you attempt the setup yourself, and post any *specific* questions/problems here in detail.  Your question covers a variety of topics which could be highly subjective in some spots, and in general is quite large/broad in scope... making it nearly impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins can run your build jobs. But first you need to create a build job that will run your script. To do this:

1. Make sure your program is available to jenkins from your VCS (ie- your git repository).
2. Create a build job that will check out your project
3. In this build job, create a script that can invoke your protractor tests from the command line.

Without any more information from you, this is the best I can suggest.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I created a batch file to run my protractor tests and it worked fine. I tried it butting in Jenkins Job by adding build step as 'Execute Shell' and put code  as 'start cmd.exe /c
cd "C:\ProtractorDemo\ProtractorDemo\spec>"
protractor RunConf.js --suite loginpage,addproduct' And execute the jenkins job, nothing happened.